# How to submit prompt=consent via ueberauth_google

Tags: google-oauth, ueberauth

When a user has already given consent for an app (e.g. when a user abandons account creation during an initial attempt, then tries again), Google will not re-prompt for consent unless `prompt=consent` is passed (see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent)). Without prompting for consent, Google will not provide a refresh token to the calling server. And without a refresh token, the server cannot interact with the user's resources (e.g. sending email on the user's behalf).

[ueberauth_google](https://github.com/ueberauth/ueberauth_google) has a mechanism for setting `approval_prompt`, but this is a different parameter than `prompt`. Is there a way to send `prompt=consent` using ueberauth_google? (Note, if I add `%26prompt%3Dconsent` to the url that ueberauth_google sends me to, then Google does prompt me and our server does receive the refresh token.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your config.exs you need to add prompt: "consent"

```
config :ueberauth, Ueberauth,
  providers: [
    google:
      {Ueberauth.Strategy.Google,
       [
         access_type: "offline",
         prompt: "consent",
         default_scope:
           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
       ]}
  ]
```

But this hasn't been merged to ueberauth_google yet. For the time being, you can go to your:
deps/ueberauth_google/lib/ueberauth/strategy/google.ex

And edit this line manually

[image]